# Image preview after capturing from camera in windows store app not working after 3rd time

Tags: bitmap, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am capturing photo in my windows store metro app using Media Capture Api.
Photo capturing correctly first it is saving in local storage then showing in bitmap image . Here is my code .

```
Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture captureManager;
 protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            captureManager = new MediaCapture();
            await captureManager.InitializeAsync();
            capturePreview.Source = captureManager;
            await captureManager.StartPreviewAsync();
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }

private async void CapturePhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
                string fileName = "" + fittingdetail.FittingDetailId + ".jpg";
                StorageFile photoFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, photoFile);
                BitmapImage bitmapToShow = new BitmapImage(new Uri(photoFile.Path));
                imagePreivew.Source = bitmapToShow;  // show image on screen inside Image control defined in XAML
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

This code is working fine problem is that on after 3rd attempt and so on image preview not updating it is showing last image captured . I check in local storage folder image is updating there but not updating in bitmap image . I am also disposing object inside OnNavigatedFrom like this

```
 public void Dispose()
        {
            if (captureManager != null)
            {
                captureManager.Dispose();
                captureManager = null;
            }
        }
```

Need help what I am doing wrong . I dont want to dupication files in local storage I tried that with unique names its working fine there . I also tried to delete file after it is captured but then no preview is shown.

Comment: Have you tried using a different file name every time?

Comment: Yes it is working fine then , but it is populating local storage even if user doesnot saving it to db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `BitmapImage` objects for a specific path might be getting cached and updates might not be getting detected.

I see a few options:

- Use a different file name every time
- Don't use a file at all, capture to a memory stream instead and load a `BitmapImage` from that stream
- Load the `BitmapImage` from a file stream rather than with the `Source` URI property